# Lilliefors-Test and Jarque-Bera-Test results interpretation

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I have conducted both of the above tests via the commands:

```
lb <- lillie.test(x)
jb <- jarque.bera.test(x)
```

I think `library(nortest)` is required to do this.

I want to test `x` for normality. `x` is a simple time series from t = 1 to t = 380 (I cannot hand out the data, but I can provide the results).

The results are:

lillie.test: `0.06***` (highly significant)

jarque.bera.test: `28.97***` (highly significant)

So can anyone help me with the interpretation? I did some searching and I also read documentations, but this only confused me more :(

What is the Hypothesis of these tests and what do these results tell me? I thought the hypothesis was normally distributed data, but I am not sure anymore.

```
kurtosis(x)
[1] 3.28458
skewness(x)
[1] -0.6423145
```

Thanks.

Comment: In both cases these are testing the hypothesis that the population from which the data are drawn has a normal distribution against non-normal alternatives (more strictly for the J-B, against alternatives with skewness and kurtosis different from that of the normal; it has low power against alternatives with similar skewness and kurtosis). What was the sample size? The skewness? The kurtosis? Can you show a QQplot (perhaps with the data axis omitted/obscured, since we probably don't need to know the mean and s.d.)

Comment: @Glen_b I added some of the information you needed and changed the variable (see the new results above). The variable is a time series with 380 consecutive observations, measured from t = 1 to t = 380. I cannot make a plot because I don't know how to do it (also I need to hand in my report on these measures very soon so I don't have much time left). So if the hypothesis is normally distributed data, both of these results indicate the variable stems from a not normally distributed population, right? Btw, the mean is 4.67 and the sd 2.89 if that helps.

Comment: Well, the data seem to be slightly left skewed, but with time series, you'd immediately suspect the assumption of independence. The negative skewness is probably the main reason the J-B has a low p-value.

Comment: @Glen_b I see, but what about my conclusion that the population is NOT normally distributed under both tests. Can I say 'according to the tests...this is the case'?

Comment: You don't know for sure it isn't normally distributed (especially since you're heavily reliant on presently uninvestigated assumptions that are likely suspect, like constant mean and variance over time, and serial independence; both these will impact the conclusion, so the emphatic "NOT" would be too strong at any p-value). You could say something like "we would reject the null hypothesis that the data are independently drawn from a common normally-distributed population; specifically, the data appear to be left skewed".

Comment: On the comment about skewness, under the assumptions I mentioned above, the sample moment-based skewness is about 5 standard errors from 0. However, that's not to say the sample is highly skew; it's pretty moderate, perhaps even mild as you can see from [this example with a similar amount of left skewness](http://i.imgur.com/6guvj5i.png). The big remaining question is why are you testing normality?